# "ConnectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED", cannot connect Node.js app and Elasticsearch database with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to make my Node.js app to talk to my Elasticsearch database when running on the same bridge network in Docker. I use a docker-compose.yml file for configuration. Here are the relevant bits and the error messages I get.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  express-app:
    build: /path/to/app
    container_name: my_app
    depends_on:
      - 'elasticsearch'
    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=local
     - ES_HOST=elasticsearch
     - PORT=3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - backend

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: es-master
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  backend:
```

I want both services (`express-app` and `elasticsearch` to be discoverable on the Docker bridge network that is created, "my_app_backend", with their service names. The official [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks) states that a "service is reachable at the hostname". My intention is to reach the service elasticsearch at the address "http://elasticsearch:9200".

#### DB connection definition inside Node.js app (server/db/index.js)

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const hostname = process.env.ES_HOST || 'localhost';
const client = new Client({
  node: `http://${hostname}:9200`,
  log: 'error'
});

async function checkConnection () {
  let isConnected = false;
  console.log('Connecting to host', hostname);
  try {
    const health = await client.cluster.health({});
    console.log(health);
    isConnected = true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('process.env.ES_HOST', process.env.ES_HOST);
    console.log('Connection Failed\n', err);
  }
}

checkConnection();

module.exports.client = client;
```

The message below shows the result of the Node.js app attempting to connect to Elasticsearch via the process.env.ES_HOST variable 'elasticsearch' (as defined in the docker-compose.yml file) and executed when the containers run. The error message shows a couple of console logs I put to check the variables had the right values.

The IP address shown after ECONNREFUSED is what the Docker engine replaces 'elasticsearch' with. This can also be found when I run a `docker network inspect my_app_backend` which outputs the container's network addresses.

```
... (redacted)
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
```

#### Error message

```
> NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js

Connecting to host elasticsearch
Server listening on port 3000!
process.env.ES_HOST elasticsearch
Connection Failed
 ConnectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.3:9200
    at onResponse (/src/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:214:13)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/src/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Connection.js:98:9)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  meta: {
    body: null,
    statusCode: null,
    headers: null,
    warnings: null,
    meta: {
      context: null,
      request: [Object],
      name: 'elasticsearch-js',
      connection: [Object],
      attempts: 3,
      aborted: false
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I want to note that the apps failed to connect on start, but when I went into the app container via `docker exec -it express-app sh` and edited the database connection code and hardcoded the IP address of the database (172.20.0.3), then re-started the node app, the app connected to the database successfully.

What am I doing wrong in this attempt to fully automate via docker-compose? Is this a quirk of Elasticsearch or am I missing something very obvious? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you just restart the Node application without changing anything, does it work?  One common issue in this sort of setup is the application starting before the database is ready to receive connections; that's consistent with getting a "connection refused" error (the name-resolution part of the connection is working and the `elasticsearch` hostname makes sense to Docker).

Answer (score 0):

Use `container_name : es-master` instead of `elasticsearch` as `ES_HOST` env variable in express_app

```
ES_HOST : es-master
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should link elasticsearch container

```
version: '3'

services:
  express-app:
    build: /path/to/app
    container_name: my_app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - 'elasticsearch'
    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=local
     - ES_HOST=elasticsearch
     - PORT=3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - backend
    links: 
        - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: es-master
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  backend:
```

Comment: This will make absolutely no difference, and isn't required in modern Docker.